# How to select data after specific character

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2012

I want to skip the first dash to choose data from the second dash.

I have used below function from which I am getting the only FLR

```
replace(right([Bin Code], charindex('-', reverse([Bin Code]))),'-','')
```

The cell contains this value

> 0771-B-3RD-FLR

Desired Output

> 3RD-FLR

Answer (score -1, accepted):

One method is just to munch the string one hyphen at a time:

```
select t.*, v2.bin_code
from t cross apply
     (values (stuff(t.bin_code, 1, charindex('-', t.bin_code), '')
     ) v(bin_code)(bin_code) cross apply
     (values (stuff(v1.bin_code, 1, charindex('-', v1.bin_code), '')
     ) v2(bin_code)(bin_code) ;
```

Comment: There's quite a few syntax errors in that one Gordon. You're missing some right parenthesis, you've declared the column name twice, and your aliases are inconsistent.

Answer (score 2):

If it's **always** from the second hyphen onwards you want (your description is a bit contradictory), you could use `STUFF` and a couple of nested `CHARINDEX` functions:

```
SELECT STUFF(V.S,1,CHARINDEX('-',V.S,CHARINDEX('-',V.S)+1),'') AS NS
FROM (VALUES('0771-B-3RD-FLR'))V(S);
```